# bash + run command in tcsh from bash

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, command-line-interface

when I run from bash shell the command:

```
bash
for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo $i ; done
1
2
3
```

but when I switch to tcsh and want to run:

```
    tcsh
    bash -c for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo $i ; done
    i: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
    i: -c: line 1: `for'
    i: Undefined variable.
```

please advice why I get errors ( I run the for loop from bash -c its the same ?
and what I need to fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to quote it:

```
bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo $i ; done'
```

In your example, the only command bash is running is "for" on its own.